# Oracle ctl file configurations for converting date time to date

Tags: oracle

I have a  ctl file for inserting data to oracle from a txt file. The code is:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE TIME_TRACK_MY_TRAN
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
VC_EMP_ID, 
VC_NAME, 
NU_ENTERED_FROM, 
DT_DATE, 
NU_FLAG, 
DT_REAL_DATE "TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(:DT_REAL_DATE), 0, 9), 'dd/mm/yyyy')",
DT_DATE_TIME "to_char(to_date(:'DT_DATE_TIME','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'HH24miss')",
CH_IN_OUT_STATUS,
SR_NO "time_track_my_tran_seq.nextval",
date_time "TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(:DT_REAL_DATE), 0, 9), 'dd/mm/yyyy')"
```

The code works well for short dates like 1/9/2020 and 2/3/2020 However I discovered that for longer dates like 10/10/2020 and 22/10/2020 it misbehaves and inserts the year wrongly like instead of 2020 it inserts 0202. I tried changing the range from 0,9 to 0,10 then 1,10 but it gives me an error that:

```
SQL*Loader: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Oct 22 16:31:53 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 17.
Expecting "," or ")", found end of file.
```

Comment: Why do you split date and time? The Oracle `DATE` type always hold date and time component.

Comment: Why did you tag "mysql"?

Answer (score 1):

Format for sqlloader ctl-file is different to SQL, I think it should be similar to this one:

```
VC_EMP_ID, 
VC_NAME, 
NU_ENTERED_FROM, 
DT_DATE, 
NU_FLAG, 
DT_DATE_DATE DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss', # don't split data and time component to different columns
CH_IN_OUT_STATUS,
SR_NO "time_track_my_tran_seq.nextval",
date_time DATE 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```